# Using Google Analytics Event Click on .NET LinkButton not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-analytics

I am trying to use Google Analytics on my VB.NET link button on OnClientClick. It is not working. Other pages on my site using same function with straight anchor links (meaning no .NET controls) do capture the event. The only difference I can tell is that .NET automatically encodes the single quote. I'm told browsers should be able to handle this, but it's not working on my page. I've also looked at all the documentation on how .NET started doing this in v 4.0 and there's no real workaround for getting it to NOT encode single quotes. I've tried the suggestions out there with creating custom encoding class and adding a reference in web.config. That didn't work for me. I got a blank page on my site.

Is there any other way I'm not thinking of to successfully track Google Analytics click event on my VB.NET (v 4.5) pages?

I'm adding the event successfully in code behind:

```
  lnkViewAll.OnClientClick = "ga('send', 'event', 'View All Awards', 'click', 'Landing Page - Awards');"
```

I don't get any errors on my page. It just doesn't successfully capture the click event in my Google Dashboard.

This is how the page renders. Which I'm told browsers should be able to handle html encoding...

```
<a onclick="ga(&#39;send&#39;, &#39;event&#39;, &#39;View All Awards&#39;, &#39;click&#39;, &#39;Landing Page - Awards&#39;);" id="lnkViewAll" class="button-text" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;lnkViewAll&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">View All Awards</a>
```

Again, please note, I did research the other solutions out there, particularly this one (https://forums.asp.net/p/1554455/3818604.aspx) and the solutions provided there did not work for me. Any other creative solutions to get this working? I'd have to imagine there are other people out there using VB.NET and Google Anayltics click events.

Answer (score 0):

Your click produces form `POST` request and the page is unloaded immediately so `ga('send'...` has no time to perform. instead handle Analytics event on server side (in `lnkViewAll_Click` handler). Something like this (in `VB`):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "gaEvent", "ga('send', 'event', 'View All Awards', 'click', 'Landing Page - Awards');", True)
```

Another option is to place your `LinkButton` inside `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Tks Alex, I placed your code in my lnkVIewALL_Click event handler and the function was not captured by Google Anayltics. I'm not sure how I would properly fit this into UpdatePanel and Triggers and such.

Comment: As the first approximation make sure that your code works on *static* page.

Comment: I did. It does.:)